# Gradient of an implicitely defined function?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

For some function $F(x,y,z) = 0$, is the gradient $\nabla F $ always equal to zero? If you take the partial derivatives of both sides, you get zero for all of them.

My book says: [image]

Which implies that the gradient isn't always zero. Why not?

Comment: $F(x,y,z) = 0$ may hold for all $(x,y,z)$ but not $\displaystyle \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} = 0$. Consider examples: $f(x,y,z) = x^2 +y^2 +z^2 - 1 = 0.$

Comment: Why isn't $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} = 0$? If you differentiate both sides with respect to $x$, on the left side you get $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}$ and on the right side you get $\frac{\partial 0}{\partial x} = 0 \implies \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} = 0$

Comment: Instead of arguing over an abstract $F$, consider the example above. When is it true? Compute $\displaystyle \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}$ and $\displaystyle \frac{\partial F}{\partial z}$. Remember that if you want all three to be zero you still have to respect the condition that $F(x,y,z) = 0$.

Comment: @MarkFantini Hmm, well $F_y = 2y$ and $F_z = 2z$ which are non zero! That would imply the gradient is non-zero... But then why is my argument that the gradient of zero is zero thus the gradient of the function is zero false?

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the derivative on *identities* only. For example, we know that $$(x-1)^2 = x^2 - 2x + 1 $$
right? Taking derivatives, we get $$2(x-1) = 2x - 2,$$
which is true. Now, this serves as an explanation for why, in general, we can't use derivatives to solve equations. Suppose I want to solve the equation $$\frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{5x^2}{2} + 6x = 0 $$

Third degree, too hard. Let's differentiate. We get: $$x^2 - 5x + 6 = 0,$$

which is easy and has $2$ and $3$ as solutions. But these are not solutions to the original equation. So, unless your $F(x,y,z) = 0 $ is not an identity, hardly $\nabla F(x,y,z)$ will be $\bf 0 $.